# How do you update a Stripe customer's usage record at the end of a billing cycle?

Tags: stripe-payments

For a metered pricing plan, rather than running a daily cron to create usage records for every customer, I'm listening for the `invoice.created` event triggered at the end of a billing cycle and updating the invoice with metered usage.

Unfortunately, I can't add a usage record because `ERROR: Cannot create the usage record with this timestamp because timestamps must be after the subscription's last invoice period (or current period start time)`. So I have to manually create a new line item instead of using the pricing plan.

It would be great if usage records created during the draft period of an invoice could be added to that billing cycle. Is that possible? I imagine it would save Stripe a massive amount of api hits if it were. Is there another webhook right before an invoice gets created I can hook into?

Comment: You can't add usage records to an Invoice that's already been created. You want the invoice.upcoming event instead of invoice.created. Mentioned on https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#tracking

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears `invoice.upcoming` gets triggered 3 days prior to the end of the billing cycle so I'd miss out on 3 days of usage getting recorded.

Comment: Metered plans are designed to track usage during the period, rather than to define the usage after the period. If your billing amount is determined after the period has ended, you likely want to have the plan be free and then add invoice items to the invoice in response to the invoice.created event. This is less an oversight and more a case of using the right tool for the desired flow.

Comment: I understand that. But why would Stripe prefer I hit them with a million post requests updating usage throughout a month (I'm tracking streamed video minutes) as opposed to just introducing a hook right before the billing period ends where I can update the usage once. They seem to have a million other hooks.

Comment: I suppose it's to encourage using a different flow like you suggest which is what I ended up using, which is unfortunate because I lose out on some nice properties of the metered usage feature.